# Nodetool repair -pr -full vs Nodetool repair -pr

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am running a cluster with 1 datacenter (6 nodes) and Cassandra 3.11.0 installed on each node with replication factor 2.  I know `nodetool repair -pr`
will carry out a repair of the primary ranges on that node.  My question, is how `nodetool repair -pr -full` is different from `nodetool repair -pr`?

Which repair option should I use on a heavy load production system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my question is how `nodetool repair -pr -full` is different from `nodetool repair -pr`?

So a "full" repair means that all data between the source and target nodes will be verified and repaired.  Essentially, it's the opposite of an "[incremental](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsRepair.html#toolsRepair__incremental)" repair, where only a subset of data is repaired.  These two options control *how much* data is repaired.

Once that is decided (incremental vs. full), `-pr` will run on that subset, and only then repairs the primary replicas.

Additionally, `-full` is the default for Cassandra 3; which would make `-pr` and `-pr -full` essentially the same.

> Which repair option should I use on a heavy load production system?

I'll second what Alex said, and also recommend [Cassandra Reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/) for this.  It has the ability to schedule repairs for slower times, as well as allowing you to pause repairs which don't complete in time.

Comment: I see the same logging information in system.log either by running repair using -pr or -pr -full,  
       
repairing keyspace main with repair options (parallelism: parallel, primary range: true, incremental: false, job threads: 2, ColumnFamilies: [], dataCenters: [], hosts: [], # of ranges: 6, pull repair: false), 
how can I make sure "repair -pr" are doing the full repair?

Answer (score 2):

For production systems, as part of  it's better to use token range repair (using `-st`/`-et` options) to limit the load onto the nodes.  Doing it manually could be tedious, but it could be automated with tools like [Reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/), that track what token ranges are already repaired, and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Its recommended that do not execute incremental repair with -PR option.
it will skip non-primary replicas unrepaired and is not a good practice in long run !!

Comment: Looks like a comment